# Power Query Syntax error when using dynamic parameters

Tags: powerquery

I'm having a problem with Power Query prompting there is a syntax error.

```
DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near ")";
Error while executing the query
```

Please see below an example query I am trying to run. It uses a country parameter as a filter in the query.

```
let
    Source = Odbc.Query("dsn=source_name", "

select *
from table_name
where 1=1
AND reporting_date = '2023-12-20'
AND country IN ("&Country_list&")
limit 500
    ")
in
    Source
```

This used to work completely fine before when the country parameter was just a hardcoded text (e.g. ''UK'), however I've changed the country parameter to work off of a slicer output as I need the country parameter to be dynamic based on slicer selection.

I have a slicer with all my countries and a helper column to pull the selected country in the slicer via this formula.

```
=IFERROR(CUBERANKEDMEMBER("ThisWorkbookDataModel",CUBESET("ThisWorkbookDataModel", Slicer_country),1),0)
```

My country parameter is then a concatenation of all the selected countries in the slicer via this formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,H27:H37)
```

Example output of above formula (used as country parameter): 'UK','IE','FR'

Please help! What am I missing?

Comment: if you hardcoded the multiple countries how does that compare to what this generates?

Comment: The parameter in the Power Query editor looks the same whether it's hardcoded or I use the formula, only difference is formula gives the error.

Strange part is I still get my 500 rows output which I can load to a table or pivot table, but the error still pops up which prevents load to data model on "Refresh All"

Comment: Strange part is  ... thats because the results are cached.  duplicate the query and you will see it instantly pops up an error.  There must be differences. You should just output the results of the Odbc.Query code in both instances and look for the difference

Comment: Can you expand on your suggestion please?

Comment: see "answer" below

Answer (score 0):

Output this

```
let Source = "select * from table_name where 1=1 AND reporting_date = '2023-12-20' AND country IN ("&Country_list&") limit 500 " in Source
```

then compare it to the hardcoded version of that code (which you know works) and look for differences